# Parsing HTML table to pandas with beautiful soup

Tags: pandas, parsing, beautifulsoup

I want to parse the "Team Batting" table from

```
http://www.baseball-reference.com/teams/NYM/2017.shtml
```

I can find the html table:

```
table = soup.find('div', attrs={'class': 'overthrow table_container'})
table_body = table.find('tbody')
```

And I can find the data in the table and store it into a list:

```
table_text=[]
for tr in table_body.findAll('tr'):
    tds = tr.findAll('td')
    for td in tds:
        table_text.append(td.get_text())
```

How can I re-create this table in pandas? I was thinking of creating a dictionary but am not sure how to from this data.  How can I scrape this html table and display it?

Comment: pandas has a [pd.read_html](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_html.html#pandas-read-html) method that output a dataframe

Answer (score 4):

You are looking for [`pandas.read_html()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_html.html) which you can point to your table using the `match` argument. Note that it will return a list of `DataFrames`, get the first one:

```
import pandas as pd

url = "http://www.baseball-reference.com/teams/NYM/2017.shtml"
dfs = pd.read_html(url, match="Team Batting")
print(dfs[0])
```

Comment: if your html page has only one table you can skip match parameter in pd.read_html.